# How do I get .__repr__() to work correctly?

Tags: python, for-loop, repr

I want to use `__repr__` in Python, so I can see the representation the way I want it to be like below.

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
        def __repr__(self):
            Repr = "Polynomial("
            for i in args:
                if i == 0:
                    Repr = Repr + str(self.args[i])
                else:
                    Repr = Repr + ", "+ str(self.args[i])
            return Repr
```

so if I enter `Polynomial(1,2,3)`, it should return `'Polynomial(1,2,3)'`, not like `<__main__.Polynomial at 0x219eb9f52c8>`. But it still returns that uninformative stuff. Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

1. Your indentation is incorrect, `__repr__` should be a method of your class. It is currently an inner method of your `__init__` method.
2. You are iterating `args` but you are trying to use `i` as if it is the index (it is the actual arg)
3. You can use `.join()` to easily convert a list to a comma separated string.

Here is a working implementation of your method:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    def __repr__(self):
        Repr = "Polynomial("
        for i in range(len(self.args)):
            if i == 0:
                Repr = Repr + str(self.args[i])
            else:
                Repr = Repr + ", "+ str(self.args[i])
        Repr += ")"
        return Repr
```

And this is a more streamlined method that uses string formatting and `.join()`::

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Polynomial({})".format(", ".join([str(arg) for arg in self.args]))
```